# How to reassemble spring assembly on Shimano M520 SPD pedals

Tags: repair, pedals

I have a pair of shimano m520 pedals which were damaged in an accident.  The springs rotated past the tension bolt and now the back section, usually under tension, now hangs free.  How can I re-assemble the pedal and get the springs back under the tension screw? It seems very difficult since the springs need to be held under tension to get the plate back on top of the springs. Is this possible with home tools?

Here's a link to an assembly diagram: 
http://www.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/PD/EV-PD-M520-2235_v1_m56577569830608614.pdf

Comment: Looking at the assembly diagram, I do not think Shimano intends them to be maintained, otherwise the spring assembly would also be exploded.

Comment: I've taken mine apart for a good cleaning and I'd also like to know :)

Comment: Updated diagram link: https://road.cc/sites/default/files/EV-PD-M520-2235_v1_m56577569830608614.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to reassemble this after some examination of the assembly diagram.

I took the body cover off (see item labeled #4 in diagram).

Then I reassembled the spring / tensioner assembly without tension on the springs. I used a magnet to hold the bolt in place while I did this.

Then I attempted to put the body cover back on.  I couldn't exactly squeeze it on due to the tensioned back section.  So, I put it on loosly with a few threads of the three bolts screwed in. It was loose enough to hang on there, but it was at a slightly awkward angle due to pressure from the tensioned back section.

I then was able to slowly tighten the bolts and force back the tensioned back section with a screwdriver until I could snap the body cover in place.

The bolts held the body plate down and prevented it from moving due to pressure from the tensioned back section. and I completed tightening all the bolts and now have a functioning pedal.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with an XT SPD pedal.

- Using your magnet idea, I used my magnetized parts dish to hold the
  adjuster bolt in place on the bracket.
- I then set the springs in place and everything just sits in place through the magic of magnets.
- I removed the body cover plate to prevent any spring tension on the bracket so I could slide the long bolt though.
- Once the springs were remounted I wedged needle-nose pliers into the pedal to spread the bracket enough to reinstall the body cover plate and screws.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem on a different model. The thing that helped me was to take off the bolt, place the springs where there should be, place the bolt against the springs, and hammer/wedge it back in place with a screwdriver and hammer